# EnvMap stops working when I change from MeshBasicMaterial to MeshStandardMaterial

Tags: three.js

In this example the env map works fine:

```
          const envTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader(loadingManager).load(
            "/src/assets/textures/table_reflection.jpg",
            (texture) => {
              texture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
              texture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;

              const reflectionMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                color: 0xffffff,
                envMap: envTexture,
                reflectivity: 0.64,
                refractionRatio: 1.98,
                opacity: 0.6,
                transparent: true
              });

              child.material = reflectionMaterial;
            },
          );
```

But then I wanted to add a metallic effect to I changed it to this:

```
          const envTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader(loadingManager).load(
            "/src/assets/textures/table_reflection.jpg",
            (texture) => {
              texture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
              texture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;

              const reflectionMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({  // Changed here
                color: 0xffffff,
                envMap: envTexture,
                reflectivity: 0.64,
                refractionRatio: 1.98,
                opacity: 0.6,
                transparent: true,
                metalness: 0.2, // Changed here
                roughness: 0.1, // Changed here
              });

              child.material = reflectionMaterial;
            },
          );
```

And now the metal shine is working, but not the env reflection anymore.

Why?